# How to get column header in excel generated via python ExcelWriter

Tags: pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I am fetching excel data from django database via raw query. excel is generated but column header is missing .
please suggest some way to get that header.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
df1 = pd.DataFrame(row1)
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except:
    from io import StringIO
import xlwt
wb = Workbook()
writer = ExcelWriter("XYZ.xlsx",options={'remove_timezone': True})
xl_out = StringIO()
writer.path = xl_out
ws1 = wb.add_sheet("abc")
for col_num, value in enumerate(df1.columns.values):
       ws1.write(1,col_num + 1, 'value')
df1.to_excel(writer,"abc", index= True, header=True)
writer.save()
```